# ShareActionProvider and action bar sherlock overflow issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm having an issue connected with actions oferflow. On mdpi device with Android 2.3 on board, when I put two actions on the action bar and then add a ShareActionProvider it overflows to be under hardware menu button instead the overflow icon.

What is happening is partially acceptable, but the ShareActionProvider does not work at all under those circumstances. When I roll over the menu panel and click nothing happens.

Oh, I'm using AB Sherlock 4.2.0.

Do you know any workaround?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Current workround for me is to handle generic **onOptionsItemSelected** for provider's ID and do as follows:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
[...]
            case R.id.menu_item_share:
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mShareIntent, getString(R.string.share_title)));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

But it'd be nice to see this fixed. :)

Answer (score -2):

- I have been used this example, in this example you have to add **/libs/android-support-v4.jar** library file and and put a break point on public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) method in /src/android/support/v4/app/Watson.java

line no. 115

debug source code when you use app for lower version api where "Menu" button exist.

### Hope you will be able to find problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you exactly mean. Well, I know what is the problem. The problem is that share action provider in not a normal menu item. When you click on it there is no **onOptionsItemSelected**, internally there is a click listener.

In my case it happens that the provider is converted into regular menu item that is visible under panel menu. Internal method showPopup is not called in that case.